# Binomial Theorem Expansion With Inverse Variable?

Tags: binomial-coefficients

I need to find the 6th term of $(4x-\frac{1}{2x})^{10}$

To my knowledge, the 6th term would be:

$\binom{10}{6}$$(4x)^6$$(-\frac{1}{2x})^{4}$ = 210*4096$x^6$$(\frac{1}{16x^4})$ = 53760$x^2$...but the answer is -8064. What went wrong?

Comment: Sixth term, count on fingers. First involves $\binom{10}{0}(4x)^{10}$, second $\binom{10}{1}(4x)^9$, and so on sixth term is $\binom{10}{5}(4x)^5()^?$.

Comment: D'oh! Sorry....thank you for catching that.

Comment: You are welcome. In principle $6$th term is unambiguous, but it doesn't quite work out that way.